# How to store cookies client-side from request module response

Tags: node.js, cookies, electron, node-request

I'm creating a desktop app with electron using a private API. When I make request I got the set-cookie in res.headers but I don't know how to store it locally.
First I was storing every cookies in one variable so the last set-cookie is overwritting the old one but with further research I found that cookies are not working like that and I need to merge the old and the new cookies response but I don't know how to do that.

Everything I find is only to set a new cookie serverside but never like the browser do.

```
let cookies

request({
  uri: myUrl,
  method: 'GET'
}, function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) {}
  if (res.headers['set-cookie']) {
    cookies = res.headers['set-cookie']
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it using request and tough-cookie-filestore to persist data

```
var request = require('request')
const FileCookieStore = require('tough-cookie-filestore');
// NOTE - currently the 'cookies.json' file must already exist!
const j = request.jar(new FileCookieStore('./cookie.json'));
request = request.defaults({ jar : j })
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually deal with the cookies, if you just want to remember existing ones.

The following example from the [request GitHub page](https://github.com/request/request#examples) makes two subsequent requests. The second request will have all the cookies set by the first one.

```js
const request = request.defaults({jar: true})
request('http://www.google.com', function () {
  request('http://images.google.com')
})
```

Comment: Thank you!  I already managed to do it. I'm not using the globar jar cookie but I'm using tough-cookie-filestore as jar to keep my cookies even after the app is closed